# NodeJS how to execute a function only on working hours?

Tags: node.js, algorithm, database-design, schedule

I need to trigger a function to send mails to users **only during their working hours**.

The function that sends mails works and I know how to perform CRON jobs.

My different users do not have the same working hours ; for example :

User1 : [9h00;12h30] and [14h00;17h30]

User2 : [8h30;12h00] and [13h00;16h30]

etc...

and it can be different from Monday to Sunday.

If all hours were the same for all users and all days, with no lunch break, I would have a couple of keys in my MySQL DB "mailEnableHour" and "mailDisableHour" that my function would check before any action...

But the problem is actually more tricky : 7 days x 4 times = 28 keys...

Question :

How would you organize the DB to store this 28 keys for each user please ?

Do you know any way to reduce the 28 keys to a unique key ?

How to get a more "flexible" code (let's imagine that I had a new break to add in the future for example [10h30;10h45]) ?

Thank you for your help :)

Best regards.

Comment: Is it absolutely guaranteed that you'd get 2 slots of work-time per employee / user every day (Ex: 9-12.30 - 14-17.30)? or can you get more than / less than that? Also - will you be querying the DB using these fields? (Example: your cron job kicks off at 11.00 and you query the DB to figure out who's working to send them an email?) Or is it an individual thing where it kicks off at 11 and you know you need to send an email to person X but just want to verify if they are working or not?

Comment: Hi Mavi Domates, no it isn't warranty but let's keep only 2 slots of work-time

Comment: And what about the querying? Will you use these fields for querying?

Comment: The CRON job always kick off at 11.00 (for example) and the CRON function should check in DB if the mail can be sent to the user (working hours) or not (non working hours). Actually, I'm not sure to clearly understantd the differences between the two cases you asked for. Thank you.

Comment: So you know the person in advance then / the query would be just to check if we can send the mail? Or are we expected to retrieve the list of people who we can send the email to?

Comment: Each job is individual, no list is needed. Yes, the query would be just to check if we can send the mail to a user, if we are in the working hours for this user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you ideally need is [INTERVAL data type](http://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-interval/). But it looks like MySQL doesn't have support for this. But even with that datatype, you would need another table.

If I understand correctly, not only these hours can change per user but they can change per day for the same user.

So

User 1 Monday:  [9.00 - 12.30] & [14.00 - 17.30]

User 1 Tuesday: [10.00 - 13.30] & [14.30 - 18.00]

If that's the case, your best bet is using another table - something like `MailEligibleWorkHours` where you can set these fields as indexes and query the users / eligibility from there. (Day being one of the columns) Perhaps your actual users table contains bunch of other fields which can help you optimize the join (like is user on vacation / on parental leave etc...).

If you want to make it even more flexible, you can have an `interval` table, which you'd have to reference the `interval_id`'s to your `MailEligibleWorkHours` table. This design would allow you to

1. Add / remove time intervals as appropriate.
2. Re-use a time interval which was already defined (like Monday 09.00 - 12.30 slot)
3. Chances are TimeIntervals won't be a huge table, so you can query everything and cache the ids + time slots which would mean you can figure out with a single roundtrip **without any joins** if an employee is eligible for mail at that time.

`MailEligibleWorkHours table`

```
| employee-id | interval_id |
|:------------|:------------|
| 111         | 1           |
| 111         | 3           |
| 132         | 2           |
```

`TimeIntervals table`

```
| interval_id | dayOfWeek | timestart | timeend |
|:------------|:----------|:----------|:--------|
| 1           |  1        |  12.00    | 13.30   |
| 3           |  4        |  14:00    | 16:30   |
| 2           |  3        |  09:00    | 12:30   |
```

Comment: MySQL have a INTERVAL() function but it doesn't match what I need. Your example matches what I need. In your opinion, in the MailEligibleWorkHours you suggest, should I enter the 7 days x 4 times = 28 keys ? Actually you talk about day being one of the columns I don't get it...

Comment: Yeah - it's the data type you need, not the function

Comment: You can further improve this design. If you don't have that many # of time intervals across all employees (or unless you add one) - on the app start you can cache all of the time intervals and just check if an employee record with a certain time interval id exists in the WorkHours table. If not - don't send an email.

Comment: @Frankie - you shouldn't need 28 keys - see the table design. With this way you represent an interval with 3 data points, a start and an end and a day. You can enter as many time slots as required, but in the MailEligibleWorkHours table, all of that would be represented by interval_id. Check out the table examples.

Comment: @ Mavi Domates - Thank you for your extensive answer and for the tables example. As you said, an interval is represented with 3 data points. If I have 2 working time intervals and 5 days / week, every employee needs 2 x 5 = 10 entries in the MailEligibleWorkHours table, am I right ?

Comment: @Frankie If they are working all of the 5 days - yes. You will however (knowing the time interval you are in) would get the benefit of querying the employee_id + interval_id and see if it exists without any joins,

Comment: @Frankie let me know if there's anything else I can help with mate. Interesting problem ;)

Comment: @Frankie I'd appreciate the green tick if this solves your problem mate ;)